# How to better toggle between view and edit mode in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am developing a user profile page, which has many boxes with two modes each - view and edit. Each box is defined as a react class `<ProfileBox> ... </ProfileBox>`.
For the view and edit mode of each box I defined classes `<EditMode> ... </EditMode>` and `<ViewMode>...</ViewMode>`. Eventually I want to render e.g. an address like

```
<ProfileBox editMode={true}> 
  <EditMode> 
    ... 
  </EditMode> 
  <ViewMode> 
   ... 
  </ViewMode> 
</ProfileBox>
```

I want the logic to be in the ProfileBox. My current approach is to iterate all children and filter them if they are of type ViewMode or EditMode. Too late, I realized that this breaks down as soon as I do something like:

```
<ProfileBox editMode={true}> 
  <EditMode> 
    ... 
  </EditMode> 
  <div>
    <ViewMode> 
      ... 
    </ViewMode>
  </div> 
</ProfileBox>
```

How could I do it better? What is the standard approach? I don't want to have to manually care about passing an id or a status to the Edit and ViewMode in the definition of the address.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
<ProfileBox editMode={this.state.editingWhatever} onModeChange={this.updateEditingWhatever} 
  editView={ <EditMode>...</EditMode> }
  viewView={ <div><ViewMode>...</ViewMode></div> }
/>
```

Or you can conditionally render the EditMode/ViewMode in this code.  To make it less ugly, a well designed mixin would do wonders.  It's hard to tell what the exact requirements are from your question, but take a look at what all of your `<ProfileBox/>` uses have in common, and where they differ.

In the simpler case shown above, you probably just want to dynamically create the onModeChange handler, and the onChange handler for any inputs children in edit mode.

Comment: I tried to avoid passing it as props and not as children, but this seems reasonable. How would you generally hide e.g. all `<span />` and all `<h1 />` elements below a react class?

Comment: @asPlankBridge you use the component like a template where it renders `<div><h1>{this.props.header}</h1><span>{this.props.children}</span>`, or where it takes an array and you can use .map to wrap the passed components in spans, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can continue to render ViewMode and EditMode as children rather than pass them as props by using logic in the `render` function of ProfileBox similar to this:

```
render: function() {
  var child = this.props.editMode ?
    <EditMode>
      ...
    </EditMode> :
    <ViewMode>
      ...
    </ViewMode>;

  return child;
}
```